# utf8 Nepali numbers sorting error on jQuery dataTables

Tags: sorting, datatable, datatables

There is no any error I had faced like this.

I usually make browser application in english. Recently, I had to make an application in the Nepali language. but the problem I faced was while using datatables for sorting Nepali data. For the characters it worked well, whereas when I had to use it for sorting numbers, it didn't work for me. I guess it is possible to sort Napeli numbers correctly.

eg:- the table should should show as following 
s.n 
१ (which is 1)
२ (which is 2)
३ (which is 3)
.
.
१० (which is 10)
११ (which is 11)

but instead it displays 
s.n.
१ (which is 1)
१० (which is 10)
११ (which is 11)
१२ (which is 12)
.
.
.
२ (which is 2)
२० (which is 20)
२१ (which is 21)

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom sort plugin to do that. This is quite easy, since the nepali characters can be mapped to latin 1:1 right away. As you point out, `१` is `1`, `११` is `11` and so on. So simply "translate" the nepali characters one by one, before the numbers is compared.

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "nepali-sort-pre" : function(a) {
        function nepaliToLatin(nepali) {
            switch (nepali) {
                case "०": return 0; break;
                case "१": return 1; break;
                case "२": return 2; break;
                case "३": return 3; break;
                case "४": return 4; break;
                case "५": return 5; break;
                case "६": return 6; break;
                case "७": return 7; break;
                case "८": return 8; break;
                case "९": return 9; break;        
                default : return 0; break;
            }        
        }
        var latin = '';
        for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            latin+=nepaliToLatin(a.charAt(i));
        }
        return parseInt(latin);
    },                
    "nepali-sort-asc": function( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "nepali-sort-desc": function(a,b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

example of usage :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    aoColumns: [
      { sType: 'nepali-sort' }
    ]
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jqwo3ct7/**

Comment: hey @SIdG'tAm - was the answer correct? If the answer was wrong, what didnt work out? If you accept the answer, you will earn a shiny scholar badge :)

Comment: sorry i cud not reply so soon as i was out for some work... thanx a lot for the help... it worked for me... thanx for support